# Does a table get deleted and re-created on alter table drop column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Question is more specific to sql server and t-sql but would be interesting to know what happens across other db products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not always, and SQL Server forces you to explicitly do this when it is necessary if you have a certain somewhat *buried* option turned on. This option is in:

```
Tools / Options / Designers / Table and Database Designers 
  "Prevent saving changes that requiere table re-creation"
```

Sorry for the shrunk image, SO seems to be doing this, but here is the item...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have covered this subject at length in [SQL Server Table Columns Under the Hood](http://rusanu.com/2011/10/20/sql-server-table-columns-under-the-hood/). The answer is **no, a drop column does not re-create the table**.

However, some tools may re-create the table as part of exposing a 'simplified' table management interface, like the SSMS table designer or schema diff tools, but that it really means that the tool is issuing the T-SQL to create a new table, copy the data, then drop the old table. And this is exactly the reason why I shun the use of all these tools, SSMS table designers included, and disfavor all diff based schema compare tools in favor of [explicit upgrade scripts](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/).